# httpclient unable to send more than two requests

Tags: apache, tomcat6, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am writing a Client-Server Application. I am using `CloseableHttpClient` on the client side for sending GET requests. I want to send 5 GET requests to the server. However, only I am getting response for only first two requests. 
  Here is my client code :

```
 import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpGet getreq = new HttpGet("http://shalakha:8089/Gateway/ReverseInvokeListener");
        CloseableHttpClient c1 = HttpClients.createMinimal();
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            CloseableHttpResponse resp = c1.execute(getreq);
            System.out.println(resp);
        }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the response I am getting :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0D4ABDC362FEC3030A5EE3709F3096FD; Path=/Gateway, CLIENTREQ: NO, Content-Length: 0, Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 09:22:22 GMT]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, CLIENTREQ: NO, Content-Length: 0, Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 09:22:26 GMT]
```

where 'CLIENTREQ' is a CUSTOM header that I have added from the server side while sending the response.

Any pointers as to what must be causing this?
The `connectionTimeout` in `server.xml` is set to '-1' which indicates infinite timeout.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code has leaked all connections available to it (which are two by default) and has exhausted the connection pool. You need to close response objects to ensure that connections get released back to the pool.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e145

Comment: I had not closed the response because i am going to process the response by passing it to another thread later on. If i close the response object it's stream will be closed and i wont be able to read the response object later. How do i retain the object to be able to read it later?

Comment: You can pass CloseableHttpResponse to another thread and have that thread close the response once done reading from it

Comment: @ok2c is it normal for Golang's httpclient with workers to be able to do about 160 requests per second and a Java client(based on HttpURLConnection) with ExecutorService could not do more than 33 per second...same client machine, same server api? I honestly just want your opinion as I have to do make some quick decisions.

Comment: "Your code has leaked all connections available to it (which are two by default)"
Could you please help me increase the default limit of two? Where did you get this documentation that there is a default limit?

Comment: The link is 404ing now. I also had this issue and couldn't figure out why this was failing, implemented as ClosableHTTPResponse and closed and now no issues...shame it doesn't seem to give any error by default in this scenario...just hung..